# MongoDB category tallies of found set

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a product collection. Most products have a category, a sub-category and a subsub-category, some only have 1 or 2 of those. I'm currently storing them in an array field 'category', it could look like ["german", "literature", "novels"], for a product of type "book" (there are about 15 types, each with their own category trees).
What I would like to do is do a search, maybe there's 10K matches, return 100 to the browser, and also present a list of categories with found-counts for the query. I don't know what the categories are in advance, and they can change also.

Different ways I'm looking at:

- MapReduce, but I hear this is "slow" and better geared for daily statistics than live searches
- One suggestion I got was Aggregation->$group: looked at this but I cannot see how that could count values instead of just summing or averaging them.. am I missing something?
- do a second search that just returns the category field, for *all* products, so I can do the counts in the production code
- do a looped search for each category and simply return count() of the cursor. For this to work I will need to know the categories obviously, and it seems like a last-resort..

Basically my question is "what is the best way?", it should be reasonably fast, and scale.

When this works, it's the same after the user clicks on a category - then the results should be tallied for the sub-categories of that category, and so on for the subsub-categories, if any.

Additional info: the collection will have a few million products maybe, as we don't have the data yet it's hard to test against that, only about 50K products currently.. future plans include a sharded setup (there's a lot of other data besides "products").
Am I storing the categories in the right way or should they be separate fields, would that help? There's 3 items in the array right now but this could increase later.
New to MongoDB, only worked lots with MySQL so far..

---

Clarifying the categories; for an example product of type "book", "german" will be the main category, "literature" a sub-category and "novels" its subsub-category. Other main categories are 5-6 other languages (for books), other subcategories are for example "academic & study", "business" or "travel & languages". Subsub-categories then depend on the sub-category (for that last, the SSC's could be "foreign language study", "sociolinguistics", ..). I am storing all three in one field, as an array, per product.
When someone does a search for "foo" on type "book", it'll find 123 products in English, 456 products in German, 789 products in French. What I want is to show a listing of all those main (language) categories in which products were found, along with the number of found products.
Then when someone selects "German", it will do another query and show the number of found German books, by subcategory (44 in "academic & study", 57 in "business", ...).

Comment: I don't quite understand what counts you need and what the data structure is. Is `['german', 'literature', 'novels']` a path in a tree? Could you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: I tried to clarify it somewhat. I guess [[sub]sub-]categories could be seen as a sort of tree structure, but not one that is defined outside this collection (atm).

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't really possible because one would need a `$group : { "_id" : "$category.0"}`, which isn't supported yet: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4589

Comment: yeah, starting to find that out too. I can get to the first and last items with unwind and group, but not the second (in this case). Might have to restructure the data afteral..

Comment: A working yet ugly hack that can be mapped to most programming languages, I guess: use `db.products.insert({"category" : { "0" : "german", "1" : "literature", "2" : "novel" }});`, that will work with `$group`.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm currently storing them in an array field 'category', it could look like ["german", "literature", "novels"]

You should not use one array for three different fields, which are "category", "subcategory" and "sub-subcategory".

Also why store language as a category and not as "language"? Add a bit of logic to the "schema" of your database, since it will help you when things become more complicated.

If you do, it will be much easier to use aggregation (which is faster that hadoop and is possible in a sharded cluster), because you won't have to query inside the arrays and you can get more accurate results. Since their values is really small so should the name of the field("c" for category, "sc" for subcategory, "scc" for sub-subcategory), like this:

```
{ _id : xxxxxxxxxxxx , name : "A novel of german literature" , c : "german", sc : "literature", ssc : "novels" }
```

> What I would like to do is do a search, maybe there's 10K matches, return 100 to the browser, and also present a list of categories with found-counts for the query. I don't know what the categories are in advance, and they can change also.

Since mongo is schema-less you don't have to set all this fields for every record. If you plan to have much different schema between products, maybe you should use different collection for each product, but that is up to you.

> What I would like to do is do a search, maybe there's 10K matches, return 100 to the browser, and also present a list of categories with found-counts for the query. I don't know what the categories are in advance, and they can change also.

Make good use of [indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/) (there are many kinds of indexes and you should probably use more than one) and use aggregation with $group and the [$limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/limit/#pipe._S_limit) to return just 100 records.

> When this works, it's the same after the user clicks on a category - then the results should be tallied for the sub-categories of that category, and so on for the subsub-categories, if any.

Here is a sample query to get all subcategories of a category (using the schema described before):

```
 db.products.aggregate([{ $match : { "c" : "german"}},{ $group : { _id : {"c" : "$c"}, $addToSet :{ "subcategories" : "$sc"}}}])
```

This query will return an array of all the subcategories that exist for the current category.

(Updated query in case your category is an array and not a single string)

```
 db.products.aggregate([{ $match : { "c" : {$elemMatch : {"german" : 1, "english" : 1}}}},{ $group : { _id : {"c" : "$c"}, $addToSet :{ "subcategories" : "$sc"}}}])
```

Comment: The number of categories might change, that's why I put them in an array; as for 'category' vs 'language', there are many other types of products with other main categories. What types of product is unpredictable, they come from many different sources - those sources also define the categories.

Comment: @Makis: Your answer shows a lot of effort, but there are two arguments I'd be careful with: 1) storing a path as an array is what several drivers do for type discriminators as well, mostly because you can make use of multi-key indexes 2) using multiple indexes might not work, since mongodb can only use one index per query

Comment: @mnemosyn: 1) Care to elaborate a bit on that? what do you mean with the word "path" 2) I mean that one should create multiple indexes for each occasion that might be needed. For the group that i mention above probably a compound index (including a multi-key indexes [being aware of the limitations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/#limitations)) would help and later add some simpler indexes for simpler queries he might require.

Comment: @MSpreij: Saying different sources have different categories, do you mean that the same type of product may have a different category to represent language or theme? Will you take that and translate it in your own schema or you want to dump all that in your database and try to structure it through mongo queries?

Comment: @MakisTsantekidis: 1) I think this is a one line hierarchy, so the categories is really a path to the leaf of a tree, if you will. 2) ok, that wasn't really clear to me. A lot of people run into this, so I tend to always point out the one index per query rule :)

Comment: @mnemosyn: 1) I agree that is how it should be, but it is stated in the question that in one leaf of the tree there may be more than one category, so i am not sure how you can represent that in array. (maybe you mean arrays in an array or something similar, but it really get complicated and i think simplicity may serve better in the long run, maybe not.)  2) Yes that was helpful of you to mention, (even though i haven't thought of it that way) i was not aware mongodb used only one index per query!

Comment: @MakisTsantekidis: different sources have different products - they might be of an entirely different type, say clothing, with therefor an entirely different category structure/tree (maybe with more category levels, too). With our current single source there are 13-14 different types of products, "books" was one example. I /wanted/ to create some type of category mapper so we could display it in a unified way to the end-user, but management has decided differently. For now I'll just use different fields >.>